# How to remove white space between text in wordpress

Tags: html, css

I am working in wordpress on a webpage. I have a box made with css where some text is displayed. What is strange is that I have no

Anyone can see what the poblem may be ?
And why is the space so big, it is bigger than the height of a letter.

[image]

code:

```
<style>
  .bottom2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .bottom1 {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .bottom2 {
    width: 30%;
  }


  .publicationright {
    width: 250px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #559BBC;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .publicationbottom {
    width: 250px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #769DBD;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .textpub {
    color: #365A6B;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
</style>

<div class="publication">

 <div class="bottom2">
      <div class="publicationright">
           Title!
      <div class="textpub">
           FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle
      </div>
      <p>
           <div class="textpub"></div>
           Title
           <div class="textpub">
                Name Surname, Name Surname, Name Surname, Name Surname
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="publicationright">
           Title!
           <p>
                <div class="textpub">
                     FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle
                </div>
                <p>
                     <div class="textpub"></div>
                     Title
                     <p>
                          <div class="textpub">
                               Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
                          </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to remove the default margin of paragraphs, set by browsers by default;

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

**EDIT** I restructured your html (set correct indents), you'll see you actually open up `<p>` tags, but don't close them. Either remove them, or close them properly on appropriate places.

**EDIT 2** As you're using wordpress, most probably [`wpautop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) is messing with you. Try to put this in `wp-content/themese/YOUR-THEME/functions.php`

```
function my_theme_init() {
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
}
add_action('init', 'my_theme_init');
```

NB: if you're not using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) you're doing it ***wrong***. So when I say `YOUR-THEME` above, of course I mean `YOUR-CHILD-THEME`

Comment: hmmm thats weird, I can't see the p tags then.  I tried your solution, the problem still occurs unfortunately :(

Comment: Well I CAN see it above, but there isn't any p code in the wordpress file. So I can't remove it I guess. It is hidden

Comment: ah, sounds like [`wpautop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) is messing with you... see my edit

Comment: seems like a good solution, unfortunately I cant access that, but I will defintely pass it on!